# Android graphView appendData() to the series

Tags: android, append, size, axis, android-graphview

I have a problem with this code below about series.appendData();

```
    GraphView graphView = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    int size = Pn_points.size();
    TextView i2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.size);
    i2.setText(Integer.toString(size));
    double x,y;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        x=Math.round(Mn_points.get(i)/1000000*100.0)/100.0;
        y=Math.round(Pn_points.get(i)/1000*100.0)/100.0;
        series.appendData(new DataPoint(x,y),true, size);
    }
    graphView.addSeries(series);
```

The graph can't show its plot at the run of the app. When I change appendData's **size** into 10 for example, the graph is working well, but it doesn't work on its own size should be.

Answer (score 2):

the last parameter of appendData is the maximum size of points you want to have in the graph. graphview will then remove the older points to avoid a memory leak. this is normally a static value like 100 or so.

Comment: Actually, he wanted to learn how to set "size" variable to get the length which supposed to be counted by total values. We can define it manually, but there is also another number after it probably.